# Once upon a time the orphaned twins [story] and [stories] went looking for a purpose

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request

We have both [story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/story) (80 questions, 15 followers) and [stories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stories) (25 questions, 3 followers), but both with no wiki entry. Looking at the questions, we have ones on Facebook and Instagram stories, JBehave test tool stories, Agile development stories, JIRA stories and many others, including [how to upload Flash to YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4807510/1270789)!

Given the low number of questions, splitting into something like [social-story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-story), [user-story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-story), etc seems not worth the effort, but there's also a number of awful questions that could be retagged and/or close-voted. We should also synonymise the two tags, I think.

Comment: That's your story and you're sticking to it?

Comment: Lets bring these stories to an end!

Comment: Unless you are *The* Storyteller... nobody is an expert on stories.

Comment: So, what's the [story] on [stories]?

Comment: So you're wanting to kill the orphans? Sounds villainous!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, Hehe yes villainous indeed, OP first notes that splitting them might not be worth the effort, then proposes that we take everything away from them, or else at the very least decrease their sense of identity by continuously referring to them using each others names.. Now people are calling for their heads.. cut them some slack I say, they're orphaned already!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm you have  the perfect surname for this

Comment: You monster! How could you?!

Comment: Why is this not a burninate-request? Those tags cannot possibly have any value to the site.

Comment: Cool `[story]` bro

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do [story] or [stories] have to do with programming? From what I can tell, These tags are either for off-topic questions, or add 0 value to the question. I vote kill them both (and any derivatives)

Comment: @Tezra Stories and Story directly relate to programming when referring to Agile development.

Comment: @jock.perkins Than you would want to use [Agile] and [user-stories] tags, but I'm pretty sure that the resulting question would end up off-topic or not actually about the user-story. I need an example of value being added by the tag to understand the value of the tag.

Comment: @Tezra - agree with you completely, I was only answering what Stories have to do with programming. Athough, playing devil's advocate, Agile is a fairly big topic area, so potentially could be worth splitting it up. Probably doesn't need both stories and story though.

Comment: We at the very least need valid, useful definitions for these tags to justify their existence (IMHO), and make sure that they are actually used in a useful/meaningful way. As is, who is ever going to search for [story] for any reason? (Other than to determine if they think it should be killed)

Comment: It seems like several of the "questions" here are more stories than questions. I voted to close a few things; if people can spare some close votes for the tags or filter on them in the queue it would be good I think.

Comment: I'm with @AndrewGrimm, as long as he brings his brother.

Comment: There are also [tag:user-stories] and [tag:custom-stories].

Comment: Also, for Facebook there is a tag [tag:facebook-stream-story]. Although I think I should be called just [tag:facebook-stories]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The tags represent at least two very different concepts (social-media stories, and planning stories), having a synonym makes no sense.

There isn't enough there to make renaming these tags worthwhile.

Simply burninate the tags.

None of the questions will lose all tags, and not much of value will be lost by the tag going away.

Comment: This, end of [stor(y|ies)] :)

Comment: I've retagged [tag:stories] to [tag:user-stories] and [tag:facebook-stream-story]. This tag should be gone in 24 hours.

Answer (score -9):

There appear to be two basic kinds of stories here.

Planning stories, and social media stories.

I would propose splitting into [tag: story-planning] and [tag: story-social].

Both are something you could want to search on (Instagram and Facebook stories share common properties; JIRA and TFS stories share common properties) and even have expertise at.

Story planning is part of programming and tools programmers use.

Interacting with social story APIs and getting it to work is part of programming in this interconnected world.

So I believe both tags are on-topic.

Burninate the old tags. Tag hinting (and starting with the word "story") should encourage people to pick one or the other when they tag their posts in the future.